# Exit sudoers view difference on apt-get update

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, sudoers

I ran apt-get upgrade about 10 minutes ago to upgrade my Ubuntu 16.04 server.
I asked me if I would like to keep my current Sudoers file or upgrade to the new one, it also had the option to view the differences between the two, so I decided to view the differences.

It then opened up a differences view in what seemed like vi, but I cannot interact with anything apart from page-up/down.

I don't want to just close my ssh session because it might break the update in progress.

Any advice?

Comment: Obviously I have tried :w and ctrl+a-z

Answer (score 4):

Hitting <kbd>Q</kbd> is another, more concise, solution.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out it's <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>q</kbd>+<kbd>t</kbd>.

Whoever thought of that is an idiot.